# How do I connect Vertica to Python on MAC OS?Will I need Unix or Linux Scripting?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, macos, unix, vertica

I am new to MAC OS , I need to know how do I connect Vertica to Python on MAC OS .
I need to know detailed steps for configuration .

Comment: You need to search for vertica ODBC drivers or JDBC.

Comment: Use the official Vertica python client:
https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/python_client/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

The Vertica Python client `vertica-db-client` is no longer actively being developed by Vertica. It will continue to be supported until the Python2 end of life in 2020, but it is not worth using as it is underdeveloped and going away soon.

In August of 2018 Vertica took over development of `vertica_python` a python client originally developed by Uber. This is the recommended way to connect to Vertica using python. I have used `vertica_python` for years (well before Vertica took over development), and even back then it was—in my opinion—the best python client for Vertica. And since Vertica took over development it has continued to improve significantly.

The source code can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/vertica/vertica-python

The documentation for this client can also be found on GitHub: https://github.com/vertica/vertica-python/blob/master/README.md

To install you can use pip for either python2 or python3

```
$ pip install vertica_python
```

or

```
$ pip3 install vertica_python
```

Refer to the documentation for a full list of prerequisites and installation instructions.